# nginx dynamic virtual hosts

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

With nginx is there a method to setup mass dynamic virtual hosts similar to the way apache2 can be configured? I'm setting up an saas application each user will have their own subdomain and i'd like to use nginx over apache2.

Thanks

Code below should be how to configure

```
map $http_host $subdir {
hostnames;
default "default";
.foo.bar.com "foo";
.baz.bar.com "baz";
}

server {
root /path/to/$subdir;

}
```

Comment: Nginx will let you use a regex to capture part of the server_name (e.g. the subdomain) and you can use that elsewhere in your configuration - it should do what you want without the necessity of setting up a virtualhost for every user. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Comment: I'm not sure I can use regex to capture *.domain.com because I will be setting up server aliases to let users setup a cname for some plans and map one of their own domains to our subdomain. I assume the regex would work similar to a wildcard capturing any entry coming in.

Comment: You can probably use the [HttpMapModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) to map server_names to the root location, so that whatever host name is sent to the server can be looked up and the correct files served. There may be another way - using the [EmbeddedPerlModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/EmbeddedPerlModule) to lookup information from a data-store. I think (not quite sure) that using Perl will let you avoid needing to reload the server with each added user. On the other hand, there could be a performance hit using Perl to look up information for each request.

Comment: I read `nginx -s reload` will reload I suppose the config files without users getting disconnected. On another forum a user also suggested the HttpMapModule, I added it to my code above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, setting up virtual hosts is definitely possible, please check Nginx documentation on [server](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server) configuration directive and default config samples. The easiest way is to put `server` config sections in separate files under `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and to include them by a pattern, like `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` in the main nginx config file.